# Validation rule for Contact Number

Tags: community, validation, validation-rule

i am trying to validate the contact no. it must be started with 7,8,9 only.

Ex: 9493654336==> NO ERROR
    6754294763==> ERROR

Can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NOT( REGEX(  SObject,"(\\D[7-9]{1}\\D?[0-9]{2}\\D?)[\\s][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"))
```

Hi friends this validation is perfect for this scenario

Answer (score 5):

You can use this formula in Validation Rule.

```
NOT(BEGINS(Field, '7') || BEGINS(Field, '8') || BEGINS(Field, '9'))
```

Where field is of type `Phone`.

Comment: Hi Anita,

Thanks for reply.

I already tried with this validation. 

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-jKyuj7FmKJMGk5ZF9PSGU5aE0/edit

This is error poping up

The data type of the contact is "phone"--- BEGIN Takes the string "("

can you please check on that

Comment: what is the type of your field?